# DBlookup combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I know this is questioned before, but i can't manage to get it work.
Is there any sample for dblookup combobox with livebindigs (firemonkey) between a client data set and a combobox pointing to the FK of the client data set available.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Always try to include also `Delphi` and a specific `Delphi-XX` version tag where `XX` is your version. You will pay more attention doing this ;-)

Comment: Thank you fro the notice, you are absolutely right.